# How to escape the ? (question mark) operator to query Postgresql JSONB type in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, jsonb

I'm working with Rails 4.2 and Postgres 9.4 to try out the new JSONB data type.  One of the JSONB columns in my database holds an array, and I want to be able to query for records where this array contains a certain value.  I figured out how to do this using the new JSONB "question mark" ("contains") operator, as documented here:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html

So in raw SQL I can get this to work as in this example:

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE roles ? '32486d83-4a38-42ba-afdb-f77ca40ea1fc';
```

But I can't see any way to do this query from within Rails via ActiveRecord.  I've tried doing a raw query using the "where" method, as follows:

```
Person.where("roles ? ?", "32486d83-4a38-42ba-afdb-f77ca40ea1fc")
```

But since the question mark is a special character used to replace parameters, I get this error:

> ActiveRecord::PreparedStatementInvalid: wrong number of bind variables
>   (1 for 2) in: roles ? ?

I guess I need a way to escape the "?" character since I want it to pass through literally.  I've tried \? and ?? with no luck.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: try this `Person.where("roles ? (?)", "32486d83-4a38-42ba-afdb-f77ca40ea1fc")`

Comment: or `Person.where("roles ? :name", name:  "32486d83-4a38-42ba-afdb-f77ca40ea1fc")`

Comment: Does it work for you ???

Comment: @R_O_R You know you can use `to_sql` to see what a query produces without actually running the query.

Comment: This question is not the dup with the marked one. It is a Rails not a PhP.

Comment: @muistooshort I checked `Person.where("roles ? :name", name: "32486d83-4a38-42ba-afdb-f77ca40ea1fc")` is the correct way to go... I tested using `to_sql`.. But can't answer as it marked as _dup_ with a wrong language answer.

Comment: @R_O_R -- I tested your second answer and it indeed works!  Thanks so much.  I wish I could accept your answer if someone hadn't wrongly marked my question as a duplicate.

Comment: @Flipper Can you flag it to moderator to open it ? I already requested. Question which is marked as _dup_ is not helpful for Rails...

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You should call this as below :

```
Person.where("roles ? :name", name: "32486d83-4a38-42ba-afdb-f77ca40ea1fc")
```

Answer (score 15):

A workaround. Run this query to find out what function your operator maps to:

```sql
SELECT 
  oprname, 
  oprcode || '(' || format_type(oprleft,  NULL::integer) || ', ' 
                 || format_type(oprright, NULL::integer) || ')' AS function
FROM pg_operator 
WHERE oprname = '?';
```

It yields

```
oprname  function
?        jsonb_exists(jsonb, text)
?        exist(hstore, text)
```

Now use the function instead of the operator in your query:

```
Person.where("jsonb_exists(roles, ?)", "32486d83-4a38-42ba-afdb-f77ca40ea1fc")
```

Comment: That's good to know. Thanks! If you want a list of _all_ JSONB operators, you can query for `WHERE oprcode::text like 'jsonb_%';`