# How to escape "?" in Expression.Sql in NHibernate (C#)

Tags: nhibernate

When i'm trying to use [Postgresql '?' operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html) within **Expression.Sql**
it thinks i'm trying to add a new parameter, and fails.
Example:

```
Expression.Sql("(this_.data -> 'glossary' ->> 'GlossDiv')::jsonb ? ?", "testValue", NHibernateUtil.String);
```

*[ADOExceptionReporter]: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.*

How to escape it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to escape the ? (question mark) operator to query Postgresql JSONB type in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30629076/how-to-escape-the-question-mark-operator-to-query-postgresql-jsonb-type-in-r)

Comment: No, it's not ;)

Comment: You have survived the gauntlet! :).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try overload using **SqlString** as parameter it might help you:

```
Expression.Sql(new SqlString(new object[]{"(this_.data -> 'glossary' ->> 'GlossDiv')::jsonb ? ", Parameter.Placeholder}), "testValue", NHibernateUtil.String);
```